# How to get first child height using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, height, squarespace

I have two col-6 inside of a col-12. I want to get the height of the first col-6 and set the exact value to the height of the second one.

This is how I tried to get the height of the first column, but I'm getting a null value.

```
var firstColHeight = $('#module-2 .col.sqs-col-6.span-6').first().innerHeight();
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: The selector is wrong... That's the only reason. Does `$('#module-2 .col.sqs-col-6.span-6').length` returns more than zero?

Comment: That should work just fine. You must be selecting the element incorrectly